# Superfish Menu: Keep subs visible when on pages in parent section?

Tags: css, superfish

I'm interested in learning how to keep Superfish flyouts open when on pages in that section. For example: When in the ABOUT US section, I'd like the sub pages menu items for "History," "Board of Directors," and "Staff" to remain visible.

Header

---

Home |  About Us  | Classes | Contact Us
        - History
        - Board of Directors
        - Staff

---

Content                   |  Sidebar

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS.

```
#yournav li.current-menu-item > ul {
    display: block !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Note that Superfish adds the following CSS to the `style` attribute of a hidden submenu: `display: none; visibility: hidden;`. That is why the `!important` keywords are necessary in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...seemed like a super easy solution. However I cannot get my style to override the inline style that seems to be controlling the behavior. Below is a part of the menu with the first flyout I'm trying to control. Here is the CSS I'm trying to use:

** I've edited a bit since my code block was messy and did not an inline style that is getting applied to the sub-menu UL. It appears to be overriding anything I do. **

```
#menu-primary li.current-menu-item ul.sub-menu {
display: block !important;
visibility: visible !important;
```

}

```
<ul id="menu-primary" class="sf-menu">
<li id="menu-item-18" class="home_btn menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-    
page current-menu-item page_item page-item-4 current_page_item menu-item-18">anchor   
here</li>
<li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page 
menu-item-17">anchor here
<ul class="sub-menu" style="float: none; width: 12.75em; display: none; visibility: hidden;>
<li id="menu-item-116" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-116">anchor here</li>
<li id="menu-item-114" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-114">anchor here</li>
<li id="menu-item-113" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-113">anchor here</li>
<li id="menu-item-112" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-112">anchor here</li>
<li id="menu-item-111" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-111">anchor here</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Anyone have any input on this? Still have yet to solve after nearly a month with no further input.